# Looping through Hibernate many-to-many in JSP

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jsp, hibernate-mapping

I'm having some issues working with a @ManyToMany relationship here.  I understand using @JoinTable and not actually creating a ManyToMany class it's pretty straight forward.

With this method, in JSP looping through a collection is very simple.  I Copied my example from here: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/  Let's say we have a collection of stocks which contain a collection of categories.

```
<c:forEach var="stock" items="${parentItem.stocks}">
    <div>Stock id: ${stock.id}</div>
    <c:forEach var="category" items="${stock.categories}">
        <div style="padding-left:15px">Category id: ${category.id}</div>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
Output:
Stock id: 1
    Category id: 1
    Category id: 2
Stock id: 2
    Category id: 1
    Category id: 3
....
```

My project requires that my ManyToMany table contain a custom column.  It's my understanding that I need to define the associative table in code, than.  So now the parent item contains a collection of StocksCategories which contains stocks and categories.  So with my requirements and looking at this example of defining a ManyToMany table: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/ it changes things up quite a bit.  So now looping through this becomes a little more tricky.

```
<c:forEach var="currentStockCategory" items="${parentItem.stocksCategories}">
    <div>${currentStockCategory.stock.id}</div>
    <c:forEach var="innerStockCategory" items="${currentStockCategory.stock.stocksCategories}"> // back up the tree
        <div>${innerStockCategory.category.id}</div>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
Output:
Stock id: 1
    Category id: 1
    Category id: 2
Stock id: 1
    Category id: 1
    Category id: 2
Stock id: 2
    Category id: 1
    Category id: 3
Stock id: 2
    Category id: 1
    Category id: 3
....
```

As you can see it's looping through each entry in the stocksCategories associative table.  I don't want that, I need it to display like the first one.  Technically speaking the category list is still a part of that stock object, but how can I make it display that way in the jsp?  The whole idea of going back up the database structure just feels wrong.

I can't query the stock collection and store it separately, I have to keep it connected to the parent object.

Ive been battling this for about a week now so any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks.
[image: stocks]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to do in your second example, why did you change the context of the outer loop from stocks to stock categories?  If the tables are mapped properly, all you have to do is traverse the second relationship in the inner loop.

The first example would just be modified like this to accomodate the addition of an actual entity representing the join table:

```
<c:forEach var="stock" items="${parentItem.stocks}">
    <div>Stock id: ${stock.id}</div>
    <c:forEach var="stockCategory" items="${stock.stocksCategories}">
        <div style="padding-left:15px">Category id: ${stockCategory.category.id}</div>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

--

For the three way join why not just do this?

```
<c:forEach var="stockCategory" items="${parentItem.stocksCategories}">
    <div>Stock id: ${stockCategory.stock.id}</div>
    <div style="padding-left:15px">Category id: ${stockCategory.category.id}</div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I messed up with the details (I'll edit my question).  The parent item doesn't contain a collection of stocks, it contains a collection of StocksCategories.  I'll attach an image when I edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help man but a stock can have multiple categories.  Check the output on my second code block.

Comment: This solution will clear up the double display but still not display it how i need.  I cant believe that this is not possible.

Comment: So you want to show every category that a stock is under in all parents, not just the current parent?  You can fix the duplicated display of stock ID just by adding some more sophisticated logic in the JSP loop.

Comment: No just the stocks and corresponding categories for the stock under that parent. If it needs to happen through jsp thats fine. It just looks so much more elegant when done through the @JoinTable method opposed to manually creating the table.